# Replace each string in c# list with new values?

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a `list<string>` which i want to use on a template to create a new list.

```
var values = new list<string> {"allan", "bertram", "some"}
```

I now want to use the list created above to create a list which contains the values

```
list<string> templateFilledStrings = new list<string>
{
  "allan = new_allan",
  "bertram = new_bertram", 
  "some = new_some"
}
```

is it somehow possible using a linq  query to generate a new list of strings, which contains the values in the list below from the list with only values?

Comment: I don't understand. How do you match allan to new_allan. Is it based on ordinal position?

Comment: @David.Warwick its just a list of string, where an template has values filled in from another list

Comment: And are you wanting to create a dictionary containing key value pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.Select()`.
Though I bet you want something else, you should improve the question.

```
var values = new List<string> {"allan", "bertram", "some"};
var templateFilledStrings = values.Select(v => $"{v} = new_{v}").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Lambda to find the index in the List and use this index to replace the list item.

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string> {"allan", "bertram", "some"};
listOfStrings[listOfStrings.FindIndex(ind=>ind.Equals("allan"))] =  "def";
```